# Compiz crash at startup

Tags: compiz

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 and every time I log in into my desktop this error shows up. I have no problem using the launcher and everything works, so what's this crash about? Should I just ignore this error, or can I fix it permanently?

[image]

Comment: I am getting this same error, but randomly.